# Type inference without generics?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Suppose I have the following objects:

```
const arrayOfDifferentComponents: HowDoITypeThis = [

   {
       component: ComponentOne, // no error, keys and value types match
       inputs: {
           key1: "foo"
           key2: 1
       }
   },
   {
       component: ComponentTwo, // error, key2 should be boolean
       inputs: {
           key1: ["foo"]
           key2: 1
       } 
   }
]

class ComponentOne {
   key1!: string;
   key2!: number;
}

class ComponentTwo {
   key1!: Array<string>;
   key2!: boolean;
}
```

Is it possible to write the type `HowDoITypeThis` without generics, such that the `inputs` in the first array item only allow keys of `ComponentOne` and the `inputs` in the second item only allow keys of `ComponentTwo`?

Just to clarify, I want this type to work with a dynamic number of components and component types.

Comment: Just to be sure : Do you want this "array" to have exactly two elements in the array, with exactly those types, exactly in this order ?

Comment: No, sorry. I want this to be dynamic with any number of elements, and any number of different component types.

Comment: What is still unclear to me is the meaning of `// should be type ComponentOne[someKeyOfComponentOne]` : is `someKeyOfComponentOne` a dictionary or a key ? Or is `ComponentOne` a dictionnary or an array (of type...?) ?

Comment: `ComponentOne` is an object or a dictionary if you will. That part is not that important, if I could figure out how to only be allowed to specify keys of the component in the object in its inputs I could figure out the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### If the Available Types are Known

You can used mapped types to create a union of possible pairings, but this has some limitations.  It will work with a *dynamic* number of component/type pairs, but not an *unknown* number.

When you are creating a union through mapped types, basically what you do is create a key-value object type and then take the union of all the values.  So the keys get discarded, but we need some sort of key at some point in order to do the mapping from `ComponentOne` to `{component: ComponentOne; inputs: React.ComponentProps<ComponentOne>}`.  I'm struggling with what that key would be in this scenario as I'm not seeing any sort of discriminant.

(side note: I find your naming to be confusing because your `ComponentOne` is the props type rather than the component type, so I'm using names that are clearer.)

If you define some sort of map like this:

```
type PropTypes = {
    one: ComponentOneProps;
    two: ComponentTwoProps;
}
```

Then you can use a mapped type like this:

```
type ComponentAndProps = {
    [K in keyof PropTypes]: {
        component: React.ComponentType<PropTypes[K]>;
        inputs: PropTypes[K];
    }
}[keyof PropTypes];
```

Which gives you the union of all valid pairings:

```
type ComponentAndProps = {
    component: React.ComponentType<ComponentOneProps>;
    inputs: ComponentOneProps;
} | {
    component: React.ComponentType<ComponentTwoProps>;
    inputs: ComponentTwoProps;
}
```

Your `HowDoITypeThis` is an array `ComponentAndProps[]`.  You'll get a big red error if you try to assign `ComponentOneProps` to a `ComponentTwo` component.

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/m02Gow)

---

### If the Available Types are Unknown

You need a different approach if you want your array to accept *any* type of component, but enforce that the `component` and `input` properties match.  This does require generics. It also requires that you create `arrayOfDifferentComponents` through a function because we cannot say its specific type.  We need to infer its generic and check that that the provided array is correct for that generic.

You can create a mapped type that maps from a tuple of prop types to a tuple of `component`/`inputs` pairs:

```
type MapToPairing<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: {
        component: React.ComponentType<T[K]>;
        inputs: T[K];
    }
}
```

And use an identity function to make sure that your array is valid:

```
const createComponentArray = <T extends {}[]>(array: MapToPairing<T>) => array;
```

You do get the expected error when your array includes an element with mismatched `component` and `inputs` properties.

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/wEVEvN)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, Linda. The types are indeed unknown so I'll see how far I get with your function solution and get back to you.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for. You've solved something I've been wondering about for at least three years now! I should have offered a bigger bounty. Using the index of the array to refer to the type of the component is what always eluded me. Ingenious.

I do feel like this should be possible without generics, though. And without using a function. If it's not now, then it should be, as Typescript knows the type of your component that is adjacent to your inputs property for any given object in the array.

Thanks again, you're a lifesaver!

Comment: You're welcome :)  It's hidden way deep in the docs that you can use mapped types on tuples.  It's in the [version 3.1 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html).

Comment: Sorry Linda, I know you've done heaps already, but I'm struggling with my own personal use case. I realise my question was stated poorly, `ComponentOne` and `ComponentTwo` were supposed to be classes, not types. If you can spare a minute, would you mind casting your eye over this [TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nr2MDN)?

Comment: Hmm so I intended for the `T` to be a tuple but it's not getting inferred that way.  And now I see that the [original code has that problem too](https://tsplay.dev/WP5VKw). I've got to think about this more.

Comment: [This](https://tsplay.dev/w8vaVm) is close, but it's seeing component as `ComponentOne |  ComponentTwo`

Comment: I've got this working now: [TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mpl7Bm), but only if I use `as const` and `Readonly` everywhere. That may have been the issue with why it was not being inferred as a tuple. [The Typescript "as const" trick](https://dev.to/adamcoster/the-typescript-as-const-trick-2f4o)

Answer (score 2):

you can use typescript tuple such as

```
type HowDoITypeThis = [
   {
       component: ComponentOne;
       inputs: {
           someKeyOfComponentOne: ComponentInputA;
       };
   },
   {
       component: ComponentTwo;
       inputs: {
           someKeyOfComponentTwo: ComponentInputB;
       };
   }
]
```

of course you can also do this

```
interface MyGenericA<T, U> {
   component: T;
   inputs: U;
}

type HowDoITypeThis = [
   MyGenericA<ComponentOne, YourInputTypeA>,
   MyGenericA<ComponentTwo, YourInputTypeB>
]
```

Comment: On your second example,, are you sure about the semi-colons inside the the square brackets?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated my question. Essentially I want what you've put in your first solution, but for it to dynamically detect my component types. I.e. I don't want to reference any specific component type in my type/interface.

Answer (score 2):

you basically had it:

```ts
type HowDoITypeThis = [
   {
       component: ComponentOne,
       inputs: {
           someKeyOfComponentOne: ComponentOne[someKeyOfComponentOne]
       }
   },
   {
       component: ComponentTwo,
       inputs: {
           someKeyOfComponentTwo: ComponentTwo[someKeyOfComponentTwo]
       }  
   }
]
```

Comment: Sorry, I phrased my question poorly. I want typescript to automatically detect the possible keys of inputs based on the type of the component.